Keep a variable between two threads in python
I'm using python Fastapi.
I am running an application that at one point launches a job to an external service. The service then sends a webhook with the job's status, a status I receive in an endpoint i created.
job launch:
job_events = {}
job_statuses = {}
class OtherService:

    def launch(self, **data):
        response = requests.post(launch job to external service)
        job_id = response.json().id
        print(f"Launched job with id {job_id}")
        event = threading.Event()
        job_events[job_id] = event

        print(f"Waiting for job {job_id} to complete...")  

        # Block until the event is set by the webhook
        event.wait()  # Wait for the webhook to set the event

        # After the event is set
        print(f"Job {job_id} has been completed with status {job_statuses[job_id]}")  

webhook endpoint:
from otherservice import job_events, job_statuses
@app.post("/webhook/")
async def webhook_handler(webhook_data: WebhookData):
    job_id = webhook_data.job_id
    status = webhook_data.status
    
    # Store the job status
    job_statuses[job_id] = status

    # Set the threading event if it exists to notify the waiting method
    if job_id in job_events:
        event = job_events[job_id]
        event.set()  # Set the event to unblock the waiting thread
        print(f"Event set for job {job_id} with status {status}")

What I am trying to do is launch the job, wait for the webhook to send the status, then have the same launch method return the result.
Except I have noticed that the job_events that is filled in the method, is empty in the endpoint, because of variable scopes I guess.
How can I make this code work?

Keep in mind, webservers typically make use of multiple workers and all workers have independent state. It's also not uncommon for workers to occasionally die and be replaced, meaning any state stored in memory would die along with them. Ideally, your web application code should be stateless -- such that even a brand new web process should be able to handle all requests. Setting --workers=1 may help this, but you should probably be managing your state in something like a database or a persistent queue, not in-memory data stores.

Hello, you're right The application runs on multiple workers which means a shared state won't be possible, and I can't set --workers=1 outside of a local run

Try to move job_events = {}, job_statuses = {} to a separate file and then relative import to places where you need them. So there are accessing the same object.
# state.py
job_events = {}
job_statuses = {}

import state

class OtherService:

    def launch(self, **data):
        response = requests.post(launch job to external service)
        job_id = response.json().id
        print(f"Launched job with id {job_id}")
        event = threading.Event()
        state.job_events[job_id] = event

        print(f"Waiting for job {job_id} to complete...")  

        # Block until the event is set by the webhook
        event.wait()  # Wait for the webhook to set the event

        # After the event is set
        print(f"Job {job_id} has been completed with status {job_statuses[job_id]}")  

import state

@app.post("/webhook/")
async def webhook_handler(webhook_data: WebhookData):
    job_id = webhook_data.job_id
    status = webhook_data.status
    
    # Store the job status
    state.job_statuses[job_id] = status

    # Set the threading event if it exists to notify the waiting method
    if job_id in job_events:
        event = state.job_events[job_id]
        event.set()  # Set the event to unblock the waiting thread
        print(f"Event set for job {job_id} with status {status}")

You also, might avoid moving them to a separate file just ensure that they are accessing and modifying the same obj.

I tried this one but since I have multiple workers I can't have a shared state

You can try to store a state in storage like redis or db. This way it be shared between workers.
